# Interpolating data to map gradient alpha

Tags: r, ggplot2

take the following data

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                 cond = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1),
                 Time = c(1,2,1,2,1,2),
                 State  = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
                 eyes = c(2, -3, -2, 1, 0, -2),
                 combination = c("1", "1","2", "2", "3", "3"))
df$cond <- factor(df$cond,levels = c("1", "2"))
```

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = eyes)) +
  ggforce::geom_link2(aes(group=ID, color = cond, alpha = State), size = 5, n = 500, lineend = "round") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#CC6666", "#9999CC")) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.01, 0.9)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(13,15)) +
  
    theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size = 12),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 15),
        axis.text.x= element_text(color = "black"),
        axis.text.y= element_text(color = "black"),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

This produces the following picture: [image]

I am trying to make line 2 and 3 appear / disappear across the x-axis by a continuous change in alpha.

the first line ('combination 1) looks right, but I want the 'combination 2' (blue) line to have alpha = 0 until point 1.4 on the x-axis and then gradually fade in (reaching alpha 1 at point 2.00 on x-axis) and I want 'combination 3' (red line) to gradually fade out with continuously reduced alpha until point 1.6 after which alpha should be = 0.

I gather that the problem is that "state" is mapped as 0 and 1, and needs intermediate values to specify how to plot the lines/alpha, but I have not been able to find a way to do this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You just have to expand your data over the gradients. If you use a `tibble:tibble` instead of `data.frame`  you can make `list` columns and use `seq` inside of it. The list columns can then be expanded with `tidyr::unnest`

Comment: I do not really understand this answer, could you provide an example of this procedure?

Comment: Ok, I have poster an anwser.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to do this you would need a gradient.
If one uses a `tibble` instead of `data.frame` together with `tidyr::unnest' one can easily generate this as follows:

```
ex_data <- tibble::tibble(
    x = list(seq(0, 1, .1), seq(1, 0, -.1)),
    y = list(seq(-1, 0, .1), seq(0, 1, .1)),
    alpha_change = list(seq(0, 1, .1), seq(1, 0, -.1))
)
```

Then the data looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  x          y          alpha_change
  <list>     <list>     <list>      
1 <dbl [11]> <dbl [11]> <dbl [11]>  
2 <dbl [11]> <dbl [11]> <dbl [11]>
```

Which can be unnested with `tidyr::unnest` to produce the following:

```
ex_data_unnested <- tidyr::unnest(ex_data, everything())
ex_data_unnested 
# A tibble: 22 x 3
       x     y alpha_change
   <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
 1   0    -1            0  
 2   0.1  -0.9          0.1
 3   0.2  -0.8          0.2
 4   0.3  -0.7          0.3
 5   0.4  -0.6          0.4
 6   0.5  -0.5          0.5
 7   0.6  -0.4          0.6
 8   0.7  -0.3          0.7
 9   0.8  -0.2          0.8
10   0.9  -0.1          0.9
# ... with 12 more rows
```

This can now be used to plot a gradient of alpha:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(ex_data_unnested, ggplot2::aes(x, y, alpha = alpha_change)) + 
    ggplot2::geom_line()
```

[image: ggplot with chaning alpha]

Comment: I appreciate the attempt to help, but this answer doesn't exactly solve the problem for a few reasons - 1) the data used does not mirror the data provided in the original question 2) the alpha change in your example goes in the same direction for both lines - in the original example, the two lines have inverse change 3) I do not get your graph from the ggplot code provided, I get 1 drawn line that ruggedly moves across the x-axis. 4) The alpha grows evenly across the x-axis, in my original question I ask for one of the lines alpha stays 0 until point 1.4 on the x-axis and then starts fading in